# yii framework, bind Params not working

Tags: php, sql, yii, parameters, param

I have this parts of code, but it doesnt save changes. Could you advise: why?

```
        $var1 = $this->url_path."/";
        $var2 = $this->oldUrlPath."/";
        $var3 = $this->url_path."/%";

        $query = "UPDATE page SET url_path = REPLACE(url_path, :oldUrlPath, :url) WHERE          url_path LIKE :urlLike AND section_id = ".$this->section_id;
        $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
        $command->bindParam(':url',$var1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $command->bindParam(':urlLike',$var3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $command->bindParam(':oldUrlPath',$var2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if(!$command->query()) throw new CDbException(tb('Cannot update children pages'));
```

Comment: there is ->execute() not ->query() (my mistake)

Answer (score 1):

If the query dont return a data set - `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` - you shoud use `$command->execute()`.

If the query return a dataset use `$command->query()`, like `SELECT`.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#execute-detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#query-detail